# Start multiple animation sequences simultaneously in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation, timing

I'm using PowerPoint 2010 and trying to create an animation. In one of my slides, I've different objects with different paths. I'm trying to run all of them at once (not one after another). I know that this can be done by **Effect Options -> Sequence -> All At Once**.

However, when I click on Effect Options I don't see Sequence.

Does anyone know how to add it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**All at Once** doesn't mean what you think it does. It's meant for SmartArt graphics, as [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/animate-your-smartart-graphic-HA010083083.aspx) notes:

> The difference between **All at Once** and **As One Object** is most notable in animations where the shapes rotate or grow. With **All at Once**, each shape rotates or grows individually. With **As One Object**, the entire SmartArt graphic rotates or grows.

It's easier to understand if you see each option in action:

**All at Once:** [image: 1]

---

**As One Object:** [image: 2]

---

**One by One:** [image: 3]

---

If you want multiple objects to be animated simultaneously, select all of them (either in the slide or **Animation Pane**), then select `Animations tab / Timing / With Previous`:

[image: 4]

Comment: Yeah, but how to start two sequences of animations at the same time, not only one effect.

Answer (score 0):

**With Previous** means that a given step will start *simultaneously* with the 'previous' one. Increase the timings of two consecutive animations in the animation pane to convince yourself, like two grow/shrink animations; you'll see them grow together, not one after another.

It's **After Previous** that implies sequential animations.